# amplify federatedSignIn returns accessToken without scopes

Tags: php, vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to use amplify for my Vue app but I have some issues.

When I authenticate manually via `Auth.signIn`, all goes fine, I get the access token, I pass it to my backend and get the data I want.

But I wanted to save time by not having to build the flows of reset, confirm, forget password, then I tried to use `Auth.federatedSignIn`

When I do this, the auth works fine as well, but when I pass the accessToken I got to the backend, ie complains the following:

`Access Token does not have required scopes`

```
Error executing "GetUser" on "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Access Token does not have required scopes"}
 NotAuthorizedException (client): Access Token does not have required scopes - {"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Access Token does not have required scopes"}
```

How do I call `Auth.federatedSignIn()` and make my token have these scopes exactly as the `Auth.signIn()`? Is there an additional argument I have to add?

I don't think it's my PHP/aws-sdk authorisation part, since it works when I pass the token obtained via the `Auth.signIn()`

Here is my current arguments for the amplify `Amplify.configure()`

```js
export default {
  region: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
  userPoolId: process.env.VUE_APP_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
  userPoolWebClientId: process.env.VUE_APP_COGNITO_WEB_CLIENT_ID,

  oauth: {
    domain: process.env.VUE_APP_COGNITO_OAUTH_DOMAIN,
    scope: ['email', 'openid'],
    redirectSignIn: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
    redirectSignOut: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
    responseType: 'code'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Auth.signIn()` and `Auth.federatedSignIn()` return different things, you can look into source for Auth Amplify in Github to see.

Basically `federatedSignIn` return `credentials` and `attributes` from Attribute mapping while `signIn` return a Cognito user, token, session, ...

So asking `Auth.federatedSignIn()` to return the same as `Auth.signIn()` is impossible no matter how you try to configure it.